# How to ignore exception and continue loop in python?

Tags: python-2.7, exception, zip

I have a python function that adds the directory to zip file in TEMP directory, but when I launch it I get an exception -> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'NTUSER.DAT'. Of course, I will not have access to this file and after exception loop breaks and application exit, so I wanted to know how to make loop continue even after exception?

```
    import zipfile
    import sys
    import os

    _DIR_TO_ZIP = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
    _ZIPPED_FILE = os.environ['TEMP'] +"\\"  +os.environ['USERNAME'] +".zip"

    def zip_folder(folder_path, output_path):
        """Zip the contents of an entire folder (with that folder included
        in the archive). Empty subfolders will be included in the archive
        as well."""
        parent_folder = os.path.dirname(folder_path)
        # Retrieve the paths of the folder contents.
        contents = os.walk(folder_path)
        try:
            zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(output_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            for root, folders, files in contents:
                # Include all subfolders, including empty ones.
                for folder_name in folders:
                    absolute_path = os.path.join(root, folder_name)
                    relative_path = absolute_path.replace(parent_folder + '\\',
                                                          '')
                    print "Adding '%s' to archive." % absolute_path
                    zip_file.write(absolute_path, relative_path)
                for file_name in files:
                    absolute_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                    relative_path = absolute_path.replace(parent_folder + '\\',
                                                          '')
                    print "Adding '%s' to archive." % absolute_path
                    zip_file.write(absolute_path, relative_path)
            print "'%s' created successfully." % output_path
            zip_file.close()
        except:
            pass


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        zip_folder(_DIR_TO_ZIP, _ZIPPED_FILE)
```

Comment: Traverse the directory with `os.walk` and use the `zipfile` module instead to archive each file one by one within a `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current function:

1. Use the tempfile module, it's cleaner and handles the temp paths
2. Simply insert try/except statements at a lower level, where you expect some elements of the yielded objects to fail.